# なくてもいいです and なければなりません

Tags: grammar

1. My grammar book says:

   > Verb/Adjective/Na-Adjective+なくてもいいです

   Is it OK to use

   > Noun+なくてもいいです,

   like:

   > 明日でなくてもいいです
2. My grammar book also says:

   > Verb/Noun+なければなりません

   Is it OK to use

   > Adjective/Na-Adjective+なければなりません,

   like:

   > 高くなければなりません
   >
   > きれいでなければなりません

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, it is ok, but as you did in your example, one needs to insert で between the noun and なくてもいいです.

   明日でなくてもいいです = It does not have to be tomorrow.
2. If your book just says "It is ok to use Verb/Noun + なければなりません", it is misleading.  With nouns, you need to insert は （or が） or で depending on what you want to say, for the phrase to make sense and be grammatical.

   The two sentences below have totally different meanings:

   ワインはなければなりません = Wine is definitely needed (in life). = We cannot live without wine.

   ワインでなければなりません = It has to be wine (for a certain occasion or to go with a certain dish).

   And yes, it is ok to use Adjective/Na-Adjective + なければなりません and your examples are both correct.

Comment: I typed "1" and "2" but it comes out both as "1".  Can someone edit?  Thanks.

Comment: Done :) Use a space at the start of line to indent and keep unnumbered lines "within" the preceding list item. Lines that start without either a space or a number will end the list and ensure that future list items start from 1.

Comment: To expand slightly: the reason you need the で in 1) is that you're taking the ない form of Nounである - the で isn't a particle in case you might be confused.

similarly, in 2) the two cases are based on Nounはある and Nounである respectively.